# Sed doesn't work as expected

Tags: sed

I understand `sed` will

1. Applies **all** instructions on line 1, then line 2...
2. Previous instructions may change the **pattern space** so the next instruction will operate on that modified pattern space (instead of the original text)

The example is:

**sample.txt file**

`pig cow`

**Command**

`sed -e 's/pig/cow/; s/cow/horse/;' sample.txt`

**Expected Output**

`horse horse`

**Real Output**

`horse cow`

The reason for my expected output is:

1. First instruction substituted *pig* with *cow* in the **pattern space**
2. Second instruction substituted 2 *pig*s with 2 *horse*s in the **pattern space**

Comment: Thank you, I forgot the `g` flag to apply the instruction on the whole line. If you could post this as an answer, I would gladly mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution command `s` will by default only substitute the *first* match, unless some flag is used after the replacement end delimiter, as in

```
sed -e 's/pig/cow/g; s/cow/horse/g' <sample.txt
```

The `g` flag tells `sed` to repeat the substitution as many times as possible for any non-overlapping match of the regular expression.

Another set of flags for the `s` command (not applicable here though, but might be useful to know about) is the single digit flags, with which you may choose to substitute the nth match of the pattern, as in

```
sed -e 's/a/A/3'
```

The above would change the third `a` to an `A` on every line of input.

See the manual for `sed` (`man sed`) on your system for further information.